# MSI RX570 on 18.04 - Audio and Video Playback Too Rapid if HDMI used for output

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, amd-graphics

This post is structured as follows:

1. Issue description.
2. Troubleshooting steps.
3. Other hopefully relevant information.

Quick note: if there is any information not listed herein that you feel would be helpful, ask for it and I'll add it as an edit to the main post.

1. Audio playback over HDMI is too rapid on a new MSI RX570 GPU running on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04. Video is also too fast when audio is over HDMI; using other audio outputs allows normal video playback.
2. Initially discovered issue after installation. Tried different configurations until a clear problem could be described. Searched Google, relevant forums for a similar issue. There were no open threads I could find with my exact issue, but similar issues had been resolved by using AMD's proprietary drivers. Found AMD proprietary drivers and installed them as per AMD instructions detailed [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html).


   Rebooted, tested. Issue persisted.


   Contacted MSI for the Linux support their marketing, product description, and packaging all promised. Was informed that MSI does not support any platform besides Windows, and installing it was the only troubleshooting step they could recommend. SMH. The last few hours I've spent trying to understand how sound cards and audio processing in Ubuntu work, but I feel pretty lost. If anyone has any knowledge on this topic and wants to help, I'm sincere about wanting to learn and understand this issue.
3. Other Information (If you feel something's missing, ask and I'll provide it)

- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS; Last updated: Today
- No other modifications to preinstalled audio configuration
- Graphics Card: MSI RX570 Armor 8GB OC

Open to all suggestions, even if it's not the solution there will doubtless be something learned from it. For those with similar/identical issues, I will be updating this post with documentation for any attempted steps and hopefully a resolution, even if found from other sources. For those of you thinking of a solution, thanks for trying to help, and I hope I found an interesting question for you. For *everyone* reading this, thank you for taking the time to do so.

Comment: I've had the same issue with an RX-480 as well running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the "issue". It turned out to be a faulty HDMI cable, got a different one and everything workd well with me.

This user also had the same thing happen to them as well, until eventually discovering it was the HDMI cable:
https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-amd-rx-580-all-videos-play-too-fast-playback-speed-is-too-high-and-sound-is-accelerated/71356/56